# Getting a boolean value if data is below of a treshold in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas multiindex dataframe with voltage and current values:

**Dataframe:**

```
a b 'name' unit
             0    1    2    3   ... 
1 1  absd A  0  1.1  3.6  7.6
          V  6   66  103  202
  2  quat A  1  2.5 14.9  nan
          V  0    3   66  nan
```

I want to transform the dataframe such that I get a boolean value for each key:

For some arbitrary given Voltage and Current, say 60V and 10A, I check the dataframe for the closest voltage value and check then whether the corresponding current is larger or smaller than the the given one. 
For the example, this should look like this in the end:

```
a b 'name'
1 1  absd  0          
  2  quat  1
```

With some for loops I got it to run but is there a nice and efficient way to do this with pandas, avoiding for loops and other iterative approaches?

Comment: Where's that `60V` and `10A` current you were talking about? Are they fixed or should be looked up in the data frame?

Comment: No, the values are not fixed. They are provided by some user.
In the example dataframe the closest values are 66V so we compare the corresponding current values 1.1A and 14.9A respetively to the 10V given

Comment: But where do you get the value `60V` and `10A`?

Comment: Not from the dataframe. I need to know for hundreds of measurements if at some arbitrary voltage, the current is above some threshold or below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach with `groupby` and `idxmin`:

```
df = df.stack().unstack('unit')

# function for each v and a
def get_thresh(df, v, a):
    v_diff = (df['V'] - v).abs()
    idx = v_diff.groupby(['a','b','name']).idxmin()

    return (df.loc[idx,'A']
              .gt(a).astype(int)
              .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
           )

get_thresh(df, 60,10)
```

Returns:

```
a  b  name   
1  1  absd    0
   2  quat    1
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html) to select separately the V and A of your dataframe, then create boolean mask to see if the value of A is above 10 and the value of V is the closest to 60.

```
amp_min = 10
volt_value = 60

# mask for A
mask_A = (df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:,:, 'A'], :] > amp_min).reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)

#mask for V by finding the column position of the minimum difference
mask_V = pd.get_dummies((df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:,:, 'V'], :] - volt_value)
                           .abs().idxmin(axis=1)).reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)

#combine both mask and use any per row
print ((mask_A & mask_V).any(1).astype(int))
a  b  name
1  1  absd    0
   2  quat    1
dtype: int32
```